# Numerar resultados de una consulta en Laravel y MySQL

Tags: laravel-5, controller

me estoy iniciando en Laravel y necesito su ayuda por favor. Quiero numerar una columna luego de hacer una consulta a la BD. Si alguien me puede ayudar sería genial:

Mi controlador es el siguiente:

```
$participantes = DB::table('participante')
        ->select('idparticipante','nombres','estado')
        ->where('estado', '=', 'Participante')
        ->orderBy('idparticipante', 'desc')
        ->paginate(15);
```

Encontré que con el siguiente código podré enumerar en MYSQL pero no me sale, ejemplo:

```
`SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum, frutas.* FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, frutas;`
```

Lo puse en mi controlador de la siguiente manera:

```
        $participantes = DB::table('participante as p', '(select @rownum=1) as r')
        ->select(DB::raw('(@rownum:=@rownum+1) AS posicion'), 'idparticipante','nombres','estado')
        ->where('estado', '=', 'Participante')
        ->orderBy('idparticipante', 'desc')
        ->paginate(15);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que el problema es la forma en que inicializas la variable @rownum.

Prueba con el siguiente código que inicializa la variable en una consulta aparte:

```
// Inicializa @rownum
   DB::statement(DB::raw('SET @rownum = 0')); 

// Realiza la consulta
   $participantes = DB::table('participante')
       ->select(DB::raw('idparticipante','nombres','estado', '@rownum := @rownum + 1 as rownum'))
       ->where('estado', '=', 'Participante')
       ->orderBy('idparticipante', 'desc')
       ->paginate(15);
```

Comment: Excelente! Copié todo ese código y al pasar el DB::raw a '@rownum:=rownum´1' me corrió.

Comment: Muchas gracias!